# Check for [Axis.Icon] for null values on Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I am learning to use the spotfire tool now. I am creating a graphical table with Icons. I would like to represent null values as Icon instead of showing ---. Is it possible to do like this?

I also try to write a custom expression as

```
If([Axis.Icon] is null, 0)
```

for which I get an error saying **"All parts of the expression have to be aggregated"**.

Can anybody help me to fix this issue? Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values / Expressions which are on an aggregate axis must be aggregated in their entirety to maintain consistency. Otherwise, the info-graphic could  misrepresent the data. In cases like yours, usually you can either aggregate all of the parts or the entire expression, or handle your logic in your table data itself.

Something like `If(SUM([Axis.Icon]) is null, SUM(0))`

A lot of people rather replace NULL with 0 in their data. For this, you need to create a calculated column or use a transformation to replace missing values in your data with 0, with a similar expression: `If([columnName] is null, 0)`.

In both cases you may still have `---` which is similar to null but is actually the missing value of a specific grouping you are using. What this means is that there aren't any rows which conform to this grouping, thus you can't force a value.

For your specific case, we would need a sample data set.

Comment: Awesome @PonnulakshmiSivasailam  glad you got it worked out